Как отличить метонимию от метафоры?

Этой ночью странный звук поднял с постели моего сына.

Метонимия тут или метафора?

Этой ночью странный звук поднял с постели моего сына.

Это  метонимический перенос при образовании многозначного слова поднять.

Книжка у меня есть: И. Мизинина, Т. Тюрина «Выразительные средства языка». Справочное пособие, 2006.
Вот там и написано: Метонимия — вид тропа, предполагающий перенос наименования с одной реалии на другую по логической смежности или наложение на переносное значение слова его прямого значения.

А это уже к словарю, то есть к многозначному глаголу поднять:
ПОДНЯТЬ,  св. кого-что. 1. Взять, подобрать что-л. 
лежащее (на полу, земле и т.п.). П. с пола бумажку, 
клубок ниток. 2. Отделив от земли, от пола, удержать (на 
весу). П. чемодан. 3. Переместить, перенести или 
перевезти куда-л. наверх. П. на лифте груз. П. багаж на 
полку. // Переместить в верхнее положение, сместить по 
направлению вверх. П. руку. П. голову. П. брови.  4. 
Придать стоячее положение чему-л. опрокинувшемуся, 
упавшему; помочь или заставить встать. П. стул. П. 
упавшего. 5. Заставить, побудить встать, тронуться с 
места. П. роту в атаку. П. в дорогу уставших людей. // 
Заставить встать с постели, разбудить. П. сына в школу. 
// Вспугнув, выгнать (из норы, берлоги, логова). П. 
медведя. П. из кустов зайца. 


В словаре же многозначность развивается на основе метафорического и метонимического переноса: одно значение является прямым, а все остальные уже переносными.


Метафорический перенос — образное сравнение реалий (как будто, сходство по внешним и внутренним признакам).   Метонимический перенос — разные существующие реалии: поднять предмет — перевести в верхнее положение — придать стоячее положение — заставить встать — разбудить — заставить действовать.

Кстати, метафорический перенос у слова поднять в словаре тоже есть, например:
9. Сделать более активным, бодрым; улучшить. П. 
настроение. П. дух. 




Словарь это конечно хорошо, но придется все слова так дописывать, не только "поднял". "Звук вспугнул медведя", "Звук раздосадовал меня", "Звук убаюкал меня". Тут налицо общая схема употребления в непрямом значении, а не словарные расширения. Тот самый глагол make

Все уже расписано, Кузнецов постарался) ИСПУГАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; испуганный; -ган, -а, -о; св. (нсв. пугать). кого. Вызвать испуг. Сильно и. И. из-за угла. И. женщину. Её не испугала темнота. РАЗДОСАДОВАТЬ, -дую, -дуешь; раздосадованный; -ван, -а, -о; св. кого. Разг. Привести в раздражение, вызвать у кого-л. чувство досады. Р. отца, мать. Р. кого-л. своим отказом, поведением. Критика раздосадовала его. Публика, раздосадованная срывом спектакля.

Дались вам эти англосаксы) Смесь языка англосаксонских крестьян и нормандского диалекта аристократов, так можно сказать? https://dzen.ru/a/ZEFA2a8dEzhGud0O

Интересная схема, вот сколько "изучаю" РЯ, а эту повсеместную схему употребления (не по лексическому значению) в упор не замечал. За терминами надо лезть в статьи, вряд ли тут метафора, так как первое предложение и второе имеют одну и ту же схему, а уж первое точно не метафора:
Ситуация беспокоит меня (Ситуация вызывает мое беспокойство)
Звук поднял меня (Звук вызывал мое поднятие)
Иван беспокоит меня. 
Иван поднял меня.

Метонимия немного больше похожа, но по описаниям из вики напрямую не подходит. Тут у нас смена части речи и пропуск глагола вызывал/заставил. В английском make используется почем зря, я все гадал, куда же он делся в русском, теперь понятно.
